# Vectorizing sparse matrix vector product with Compressed Sparse Row SegFault

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, sse, simd

I would like to vectorize the matrix vector multiplication where the matrix is stored in Compressed Sparse Row format, I wrote a first version but I get a segmentation fault. Sadly I haven't been able to find out the problem.

```
void SpMSpV2(gsl_spmatrix *C, double *x, double *ret)
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < C->size1; ++i)
   {
       __m128d tmp = _mm_setzero_pd();
       std::cout << i << " start" << std::endl; // debug
       std::cout << C->p[i] << ", " << C->p[i+1] << std::endl; // debug
       for (int j = C->p[i]; j < C->p[i+1]; j += 2)
       {
          std::cout << j << ", " << ", "; // debug
          __m128d data = _mm_load_pd(&C->data[j]);
          __m128d xval = _mm_load_pd(&x[C->i[j]]);
          tmp = _mm_add_pd(tmp, _mm_mul_pd(data,xval));
       }
       std::cout << std::endl << i << " ok" << std::endl; // debug

        tmp = _mm_hadd_pd(tmp, tmp);
       _mm_store_pd(&ret[i], tmp);
   }
}
```

This is the output I am getting :

```
0 start
0, 4
0, , 2, , 
0 ok
1 start
4, 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Agree with @user0042 `i < C->size1` and `C->p[i+1]` allows the the index to exceed `C->size1`. Minimal debugging effort will spot this.

Comment: `std::cout << j << ", " << ", "; // debug` -- You should have printed the value of `i` and `i+1`.

Comment: @user4581301 but the index exceeding the row count by one is normal. Otherwise it would be impossible to know how big the last row is.

Comment: `_mm_load_pd` requires the pointer to be 16-aligned, these pointers do not look like they are necessarily sufficiently aligned. Likely you are looking for `_mm_loadu_pd`.

Comment: Don't I look the fool. My apologies.